# AWS assume iam roles vs gcp's json files with private keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

One thing I dislike about Google Cloud Platform (GCP) is its less baked-in security model around roles/service accounts.

Running locally on my laptop, I need to use the service account's key specified in a JSON file. In AWS, I can just assume a role I have been granted access to assume (without needing to carry around a private key). Is there an analogue to this with GCP?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to try and answer this. I have the AWS Security Specialty (8 AWS certifications) and I know AWS very well. I have been investing a lot of time this year mastering Google Cloud with a focus on authorization and security. I am also an MVP Security for Alibaba Cloud.

AWS has a focus on security and security features that I both admire and appreciate. However, unless you really spend the time to understand all the little details, it is easy to implement poor/broken security in AWS. I can also say the same about Google security. Google has excellent security built into Google Cloud Platform. Google just does it differently and also requires a lot of time to understand all the little features / details.

In AWS, you cannot just assume a role. You need an AWS Access Key first or be authenticated via a service role. Then you can call STS to assume a role. Both AWS and Google make this easy with AWS Access Keys / Google Service Accounts. Whereas AWS uses roles, Google uses roles/scopes. The end result is good in either platform.

Google authentication is based upon OAuth 2.0. AWS authentication is based upon Access Key / Secret Key. Both have their strengths and weaknesses. Both can be either easy to implement (if you understand them well) or a pain to get correct.

The major cloud providers (AWS, Azure, Alibaba, Google, IBM) are moving very fast with a constant stream of new features and services. Each one has strengths and weaknesses. Today, there is no platform that offers all the features of the others. AWS today is ahead both in features and market share. Google has a vast number of services that outnumber AWS and I don't know why this is overlooked. The other platforms are catching up quickly and today, you can implement enterprise class solutions and security with any of the cloud platforms.

Today, we would not choose only Microsoft or only Open Source for our application and server infrastructure. In 2019, we will not be chosing only AWS or only Google, etc. for our cloud infrastructure. We will mix and match the best services from each platform for our needs.

Comment: but can you create a custom scope? In aws I can have a single/user account but multiple roles it has access to assume (I guess i still need one private key in my .aws/credentials file). All those roles have specific custom permissions, but scopes are built-in and define access to project wide services correct?

Comment: You build your custom roles similar to AWS. You take permissions (read, write, create, etc) and combine them into a role that you assign to a User or Service Account. In this regard, AWS and Google are very similar. The difference is in how you deploy those credentials.

Comment: Scopes. Scopes are the legacy method of specifying permissions. They are still used extensively in Google IAM. You do not create custom scopes, instead you create custom roles. Scopes are similar to predefined roles with a collection of permissions.

Comment: ok but you must organize your whole gcp deployment into many projects then (which I think is best practice?) in order to use roles correctly. Because roles can only grant project wide permissions- unless I can give a role access to a single bucket or a single queue or big query table.

Comment: Incorrect. You create custom roles and assign them to custom or default service accounts. You can have (I think) 1,000 service accounts per project. Google does not yet offer the granularity of IAM permissions (Conditions) on roles. In AWS, best practices are to create separate accounts and consolidate them. In Google, you create separate projects and they are already consolidated under one account. Google's project/account/organization/billing is implemented better compared to AWS IMHO.

Comment: can i give a role access to a specific bucket or big query table?

Comment: No, Google does not have IAM permission granularity (Conditions) yet. For this concept use Projects. Let's say that you have two Bigquery datasets. You want to assign permission to Bob for "A" and Jim to "B". Use two projects and have the datasets in different projects. This is a different method of implementation but very easy to implement and control and to get correct.

Comment: Update for my last comment. Google is now implementing "Identity" based access that can be assigned to individual services such as a Compute Engine VM instance, a Cloud Storage object, etc. This is very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the Getting Started with Authentication [1] page, for service accounts it is needed the key file in order to authenticate.

From [2]: You can authenticate to a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API using service accounts or user accounts, and for APIs that don't require authentication, you can use API keys.

Service and user accounts needs the key file to authenticate. Taking this information into account, there is no manner to locally authenticate without using a key file.

Links:

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
[2] https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/